# jquery FadeOut for a Class, Runs Multiple Times, instead of Simultaneously, y?

Tags: jquery, effects, fadeout

I have a page with the several divs like:

By default all are display:none, and I let the user click to show a certain card.

Every time the user clicks to load a card I run the following JQUERY:

```
$('.carditem').fadeOut( function() {alert(1)
// Animation complete show correct card
$('#' + toogleID).fadeIn();
});
```

What's surprising me is that the alert above is happening 5 times, not 1 time. Meaning the fadeOut isn't running Simultaneously but looping over all the card items. This makes for a ugly animation that blinks. How can I get fadeout for all the matching classes to run at the same time? Or just run on the classes that have divs that are displaying, which should only be 1 card?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like this doesn't work? $('.carditem:visible').fadeOut( function()....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take out the alert which is stopping the animations (causing an offset start), it'll behave as expected, at least in terms of the initial animations being simultaneous.:

```
$('.carditem:visible').fadeOut( function() {
  $('#' + toogleID).fadeIn();
});
```

Each element *does* animate independently, if you want the [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) to happen after the *last* one of them, then check if any are still animating with [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and the [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/), like this:

```
$('.carditem:visible').fadeOut( function() {
  if(!$('.carditem').is(':animated')) //are any still animating?
    $('#' + toogleID).fadeIn();
});
```

The [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) addition to the selector is so that only visible ones are faded out, rather than showing/fading all of them.

Comment: For some reason that display and then fadesOut

Comment: @nobosh - You can add `:visible` for that, one moment and I'll update.

Comment: Strange, it still fadesIn then out

Comment: Is visible supported like used above in the latest JQUERY?

Comment: @nobosh - Yep, it's been around for some time...are you using `display` or `visibility` when hiding the elements?  `.fadeOut()` will set `display: none;` when it's done, but is there something else going on outside the question?